# Distinct in HIVE keep all variables

Tags: sql, hive, distinct

I want keep all 10 variables from the old table but only select distinct records based on 3 variables (var1 var2 var3), how do I keep all 10 variables in the new table in HIVE?
[image: example]

(create table new as
SELECT DISTINCT
var1, var2, var3
from old);

Comment: . . SQL uses the term "columns" to describe attributes in a table, not "field".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` -- if you don't care about which rows are selected:

```
select . . .    -- whatever columns you want
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by var1, var2, var3 order by var1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: I should have said that I have 100 columns/variables that I don't want to list but if I do select *, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @FunT . . . Your question explicitly states uniqueness on three columns out of 10.  And this same idea works.  You need to list the columns.  Perhaps a spreadsheet can help.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, my apologies  I am new to this forum. I posted an example, hopefully that explains it better what I am after.